# Docker failing to resolve archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, docker

All of a sudden I cannot build a container requires access to archive.ubuntu.com. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update && apt install -y wget && \
    wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    apt update && \
    apt install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0 && \
    apt install -y build-essential && \
    apt install -y cmake && \
    apt install -y libssl-dev && \
    apt install -y libgpiod-dev  && \
    apt install -y libi2c-dev && \
    apt install -y tmux && \
    apt install -y systemctl && \
    apt install -y git build-essential libjansson-dev libi2c-dev libgpiod-dev libsensors4-dev libz-dev libsystemd-dev
```

Going to archive.ubuntu.com in my browser does not seem quite right either. I can click on the ubuntu folder and it seems as if something may be broken. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxFN3.png)

I can keep clicking on Ubuntu and it just keeps going deeper.

Error that I get:

```
[+] Building 168.9s (6/11)                                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.28kB                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                                      0.3s
 => CACHED [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:c9820a44b950956a790c354700c1166a7ec648bc0d215fa438d3a339812f1d01                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                    0.4s
 => => transferring context: 1.55MB                                                                                                                  0.4s
 => ERROR [2/8] RUN apt update && apt install -y wget &&     wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.d  168.6s
------                                                                                                                                                    
 > [2/8] RUN apt update && apt install -y wget &&     wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&     dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&     rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&     apt update &&     apt install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0 &&     apt install -y build-essential &&     apt install -y cmake &&     apt install -y libssl-dev &&     apt install -y libgpiod-dev  &&     apt install -y libi2c-dev &&     apt install -y tmux &&     apt install -y systemctl &&     apt install -y git build-essential libjansson-dev libi2c-dev libgpiod-dev libsensors4-dev libz-dev libsystemd-dev:                                                                                                                  
#0 0.374 
#0 0.374 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#0 0.374 
#0 56.42 Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
#0 56.42   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
#0 56.44 Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
#0 56.44   Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
#0 112.5 Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
#0 112.5   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
#0 168.5 Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
#0 168.5   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
#0 168.5 Reading package lists...
#0 168.5 Building dependency tree...
#0 168.5 Reading state information...
#0 168.5 All packages are up to date.
#0 168.5 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
#0 168.5 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
#0 168.5 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
#0 168.5 W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
#0 168.5 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
#0 168.5 
#0 168.5 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#0 168.5 
#0 168.5 Reading package lists...
#0 168.5 Building dependency tree...
#0 168.5 Reading state information...
#0 168.5 E: Unable to locate package wget
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   2 |     
   3 | >>> RUN apt update && apt install -y wget && \
   4 | >>>     wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
   5 | >>>     dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
   6 | >>>     rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
   7 | >>>     apt update && \
   8 | >>>     apt install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0 && \
   9 | >>>     apt install -y build-essential && \
  10 | >>>     apt install -y cmake && \
  11 | >>>     apt install -y libssl-dev && \
  12 | >>>     apt install -y libgpiod-dev  && \
  13 | >>>     apt install -y libi2c-dev && \
  14 | >>>     apt install -y tmux && \
  15 | >>>     apt install -y systemctl && \
  16 | >>>     apt install -y git build-essential libjansson-dev libi2c-dev libgpiod-dev libsensors4-dev libz-dev libsystemd-dev
  17 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt update && apt install -y wget &&     wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&     dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&     rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&     apt update &&     apt install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0 &&     apt install -y build-essential &&     apt install -y cmake &&     apt install -y libssl-dev &&     apt install -y libgpiod-dev  &&     apt install -y libi2c-dev &&     apt install -y tmux &&     apt install -y systemctl &&     apt install -y git build-essential libjansson-dev libi2c-dev libgpiod-dev libsensors4-dev libz-dev libsystemd-dev" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

What I have tried:

I verified that the docker daemon.json has the correct DNS IPs.

EDIT: Output of getfacl

```
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Comment: I had this problem, because of extended file attributes (fsetacl) in the docker root folder. Could you add the output of `getfacl yourdockerroot` to the question.

Comment: @Marco user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x